# How to get a substring of a given string?

Tags: c, ansi-c

I need to get the first real number from a given string(after a `,`)
for example:

```
char *line = "The num is, 3.444 bnmbnm";
//get_num returns the length of the number staring from index i
if(num_length = get_num(line, i))
  {
    printf("\n Error : Invalid parameter - not a number \n");
    return;
``}

help = (char *)malloc(num_length + 1);
if(help == NULL){
    printf("\n |*An error accoured : Failed to allocate memory*| \n");
    exit(0);
}
r_part = help;
memcpy(r_part, &line[i], num_length);
r_part[num_length] = '\0';
re_part = atof(r_part);
free(r_part);
```

I need `num` to be the given number - "3.444"

Comment: use [strstr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/), there is one example mentioned in the link, replicate it.

Comment: the point is that this string is an example, the number can be any number

Comment: Welcome on SO. What did you try before asking? What resource did you read?

Comment: the ascii for numbers 0-9 is #48-#57. so you need to find those. also check for comma or period if they are placed in between two numbers by their ascii (#44 and #46). good luck

Comment: isdigit() may come in handy

Comment: Look for the comma via `strchr`. When found, skip over it, then `sscanf` the value from that point in the string as the input buffer, using `%f` into a `float` address. If `sscanf` returns `1`, you have your value. *That's it.* It throws out nearly all of the code  you presented in this question.

Comment: If by "ansi-c" you mean just "according to the C standard" you may omit this tag and even the mention. If by  ans-c you mean the history 1989 version of C, you should consider to upgrade.

Comment: `if(num_length = get_num(line, i)){...}` :: this will only evaluate to false if num_length is zero,so `malloc(num_length + 1);` will always allocate exactly 1 byte of memory.

Comment: when posting a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: OT: regarding: `help = (char *)malloc(num_length + 1);`  When calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`,  The returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `printf("\n |*An error accoured : Failed to allocate memory*| \n");`  1) Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  2)  when the error indication is from a C library function, then should also output to `stderr`, the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  This is all easily handled by calling `perror( "my error message" );  Note: returned 0 (as in: `exit( 0 );` is a bad idea.  Typically 0 is used to indicate success, so calling `exit(0)` result in misleading information.  Suggest: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: the function: `get_num()` seems to be the root of the problem, but the posted code does not contain the function contents.

Comment: regarding: `if(num_length = get_num(line, i))`  later in the code, the variable `i` is expected to contain an index into the array `line[]`  however, to do that the function: `get_num()` must have the address of `i`, not the contents of `i`  Suggest the signature for `get_num()` should be: `int get_num( char*, int* )` Then the statement would be:  `if( num_length = get_num( line, &i ) )`  Note: use appropriate horizontal spacing for readability.  Also, the compiler will complain that there should be a set of parens around: `num_length = get_num(line, i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the "string" functions already available instead of writing your own parsing. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *line = "The num is, 3.444 bnmbnm";
    char* p = strchr(line, ',');               // Find the first comma
    if (p)
    {
        float f;
        if (sscanf(p+1, "%f", &f) ==1)     // Try to read a float starting after the comma (i.e. the +1)
        {
            printf("Found %f\n", f);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("No float after comma\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No comma\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```